# Redux: combine data from multiple json files into one state

Tags: json, dictionary, redux, store

I'm new to redux and trying to map an initial state to store from three different json files. Components in the app use bits from different files but as I understand it, store needs one single state-of-everything to pass to components.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
import data1 from './data1.json'
import data2 from './data2.json'
import data3 from './data3.json'
import storeFactory from './store'

const initialState = (localStorage["redux-store"]) ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage["redux-store"]) :
    data1 + data2 + data3

const store = storeFactory(initialState)
console.log(store.getState())
store.subscribe(saveState)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each JSON's root is an object, I would use the [`_.extend()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assignIn) function from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for this kind of thing:

```
import data1 from './data1.json'
import data2 from './data2.json'
import data3 from './data3.json'
combined = _.extend({},
    data1,
    data2,
    data3
)
```

Then you can pass that object into redux as per usual.

EDIT: Based on comments, if each of the JSON objects are structured like

```
{
    data: [{
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        ...
    }]
}
```

then you'd have to combine them like this:

```
combined = _.extend({},
    data1.data[0],
    data2.data[0],
    data3.data[0]
)
```

assuming that there really is only one item in each `data`'s array.

Comment: Each is like this: {"data": [{ "key": "value", "key": 10 }]} ... so I get an 'unexpected key "data" found in preloaded state' error. How do I get around that?

Comment: Updated according to your comment